# Seagate Barracuda shows 5900 rpm instead of 7200

Tags: hard-drive

A couple of days ago I bought a 2TB Seagate Barracuda hard drive, advertised everywhere as 7200 rpm. I tested it yesterday with the CrystalDiskInfo tool, I noticed that the RPM shown was 5900RPM instead of the 7200RPM.

I wasn't able to use any other tool to check the drive.
Is this an isolated problem? I couldn't find anywhere if this drive works while idle at lower RPM.

Hard drive model-> ST2000DM006

Comment: What was the data transfer speed from the drive?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't able to provide more info, I'm currently at work. I did take a photo of the screen and shows the tab "Transfer Mode" SATA/600 | SATA/600

Comment: The Seagate [datasheet](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/3-5-barracudaDS1900-11-1806GB-en_GB.pdf) agrees that it should be 7200 RPM, though there is another 2TB model that runs at 5400 RPM... Are you sure you trust CrystalDiskInfo to correctly report such information?

Comment: @Attie To be honest. this is like the 6th time I use this tool, mostly to check SSD's status.

Comment: It *could* be that the drive has a variable speed motor and at the time when Crystal checked it the speed was reported low. The first question would be: is this an *actual problem*, as in the drive is physically slow, or is it just that it is reporting an unexpected number? Knowing the transfer speed from the drive would give a better idea of whether there is something wrong. Try https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskmark/ screenshots from both tools would be good.

Comment: @Mokubai I thought about that, but didn't find any information to back it up. It is showing that number, didn't bother to test it in case something went wrong.

Comment: @Mokubai I'll try later when I'm off work. I appreciate the attention.

Comment: The 4TB drive in a close series is apparently 5900 RPM according to some sources and with other sources I can find 7200 rpm drives in a similar range (last digit of the model number is different). It appears that Samsung also want to move away from rpm as a speed measure as it is not mentioned in their datasheets. https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/desktop-hdd-8tbDS1770-9-1603UK-en_GB.pdf it may just be that they give you an expected data speed and that is that.

Comment: @Mokubai I finally had chance to test the HD with the tool, here are the results 
https://imgur.com/a/yAZeMD2

Answer (score 0):

Seagate's specifications say the "spindle speed" RPM for this drive is 7200 ± 0.2%.  This is between 7186 to 7214 RPM.  There's no mention of other speeds in other power states.

CrystalDiskInfo reports the "[rotation rate](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/crystaldiskinfo-general-information/)" based on the drive's ATA8-ACS "Identify Device" data, specifically Word 217 (Nominal Media Rotation Rate).

I don't believe it's bug with CrystalDiskInfo because this is relatively simple, and a value of 5900 is common for other models.  It's possible Seagate made a mistake, and wrote the wrong value, or a firmware update wrote the wrong value.  It's also possible the drive is counterfeit, and the counterfeiters were lazy and only faked some values (such as the model).

How can we measure the RPM without relying on the Identify Device data?  On another forum, someone named "fzabkar" [posted](https://community.wd.com/t/check-hard-disk-motor-speed/13555/2) a creative way to do this:

> One way you could estimate the RPM is by examining the spread of data points in the graph of access time in HD Tune’s read benchmark.
>
> For example, in the following graph you can see that, at the 450GB mark, the band of data points are about 8 msec wide.
>
> The total access time is the time required to seek to the target cylinder, plus the time required for the target sector to pass under the read/write head. The latter time component can vary from 0 to one full revolution. Therefore this “rotational latency” will be seen as a band whose width is 8.33 ms in the case of a 7200 RPM drive, and about 11ms for a 5400 RPM drive.

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate the effort in trying to help. I finally had a chance to do a more in depth research and following the Serial number found that in fact, the HD was ST2000VM003 instead of the mentioned above. I already contact the seller(Which is a highly rated one), just waiting to hear from them. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Following the hard drive serial number, it turns out it wasn't a **ST2000DM006**, instead I received a **ST2000VM003** which has lower RPM and R/W speeds but the same SIZE storage. See the pictures here-> https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5VCB.jpg

So, the most probable situation is that the Company made the mistake to print a different label o the HD(as @Mokubai said before), or I am being part of a scam(which was my first thought)

**Thank you.**

Comment: I didn't actually mention a scam, more that there are a range of very similar part numbers that have different specifications. It might well be that whoever sold it to you did not know any better, after all Barracuda drives *used* to be their performance range.